# Can't get the elements of the sencha store

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, store

So I have a store

```
Ext.define('APN.store.BackupShow', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  requires: [
    'APN.model.ScheduledShow'
  ],
  config: {
    model: 'APN.model.ScheduledShow',   
    proxy: {
      type: 'ajax',
      url: '',
      reader: {
        type: 'xml',
        record: 'item',
        rootProperty: 'xml'
      }
    }
  },
  getShow: function () {
    if (this.getData().length greater 1) # by some reason stackoverflow didn't allow me to put greater sign in here;
      return null;

    // Copy field data across as wrong field is popped.
    this.getAt(0).set("listimage", this.getAt(0).get("onairimage"));
    this.getAt(0).set("isbackup", "true");      
    return this.getAt(0);   
  }
});
```

And when I'm trying to call the first element of the store I get `undefined`, however the element exists in the store:

```
 (0) console.log(backupShowStore);
 (1) console.log(backupShowStore.data); 
 (2) console.log(backupShowStore.getData().all);
 (3) console.log(backupShowStore.getData().all.length);
 (4) console.log(backupShowStore.getData().all.getAt(0));
```

I got back:

(1)

```
Class
 _data: Class
 _model: function () {
 _modelDefaults: objectClass
 _proxy: Class
 _remoteFilter: false
 _remoteSort: false
 _storeId: "backupShow"
 _totalCount: null
 config: objectClass
 data: Class
 _autoFilter: true
 _autoSort: true
 _filterRoot: "data"
 _sortRoot: "data"
 all: Array[1]
  0: Class
   _data: Object
   data: Object
    bufferingProgress: null
    contentlink: null
    description: null
    facebooklink: "http://www.facebook.com/mixmelbourne"
    id: "ext-record-45"
    isbackup: null
    listimage: null
    onairimage: "http://arntrnassets.mediaspanonline.com/radio/mxm/53808/on-air-default_v3.png"
    showbody: "Melbourne's widest variety from 2K to today, Mix101.1 with Chrissie & Jane waking up Melbourne weekdays from 6am."
    showbyline: "The widest variety from 2K to today"
    showcontentxml: null
    showemail: null
    showname: "Mix 101.1"
    showschedule: null
    smallimage: null
    title: null
    twittername: "mixmelbourne"
    __proto__: Object
    id: "ext-record-45"
    internalId: "ext-record-45"
    modified: Object
    phantom: true
    raw: item
    stores: Array[1]
    __proto__: TemplateClass
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

(2)

```
_autoFilter: true
_autoSort: true
_filterRoot: "data"
_sortRoot: "data"
all: Array[1]
config: objectClass
dirtyIndices: true
getKey: function (record) {
indices: Object
initConfig: function (){}
initialConfig: Object
items: Array[1]
keys: Array[1]
length: 1
map: Object
__proto__: TemplateClass
```

(3)

```
Array[1]
  0: Class
  length: 1
  __proto__: Array[0]
```

(4)

```
0
```

(5)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'getAt'
```

Which is understandable for (5) as array doesn't have method getAt, however the store doesn't have any items and that is indicated by (4) where the array of getData elements equals to 0...

Am very confused at this point of time with Sencha Touch Framework and how to get the first element of an array of elements

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the [Ext.data.Store.first() method](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-first).

I have found I am typically a happier developer when I use the methods provided by the api. On the rare occasion that I need something not provided I will navigate the Sencha Objects myself but I really try not to.

Let me know if and why that solution might not work and I'll try to find something else for you.